# Deploying pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

So Ive been trying to deploy my pyqt code for windows using pyinstaller and it builds the .exe file but it keeps saying "fatal error: cant execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap"

I installed all modules that are used in my code an I really need some help because the deadline is near

I also tried some of the solution but didnt work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look this project called : FBS](https://build-system.fman.io/)

I used this with PyQt/PySide projects after failed with : pyqtdeploy, pyinstaller, cx_Freeze and anothers .

But this save my life , just open website and 'Visit tutorial ' and be happy

Comment: Thanks iot it did the trick